# Usage of past participles

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, reduced-relative-clauses

> 1- The funeral is at 3.00, ***followed*** by a reception at Shawn's bar.

I saw this sentence in a tv-series. Can I say that this sentence is a reduced form of the sentences below?

> 2- The funeral is at 3.00, ***which is followed*** by a reception at Shawn's
>   bar.
>
> 3- The funeral is at 3.00, ***which will be followed*** by a reception
>   at Shawn's bar.

Comment: Assuming that *X bar* itself makes sense (a complete phrase would be more helpful), then there's nothing wrong with the sentence. And any number of expansions would be possible, including a simple conjunction like *and [something] followed*.

Comment: No, it's not a reduced form of the version with which - it's just more information tacked on to the end. If it's a reduced form of anything, it would be *and will be followed*. The versions with *which* are incorrect for me. If you really wanted to use *which* it would be *the funeral, which will be followed by drinks at Shawn's bar, is at 3*, or *there will be a reading at 3, which will be followed by*. Your structure would be used in a sentence like *the funeral will be at 8pm, which is to accommodate those flying in from abroad*.